# SVN Error E175002 while checking out code from repository

Tags: apache, svn, webdav, svn-checkout

While trying to checkout code from a repository online I got the following error:

> E175002: REPORT of '/repos/xxx/!svn/vcc/default'

I am trying to checkout the code from a remote computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After long research, I finally found a solution the solution was to put `allow from all` in the svn configuration on `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory /repos>
...
allow from all
...
</Directory>
```

The svn checkout is working fine now

The above are for apache 2.2

if you use apache 2.4

```
<Directory /repos>
    ...
    require all granted
    ...
    </Directory>
```

Comment: In 1.7.2 the support for Directory directives is lost as mod_dav_svn will no longer map URLs to the filesystem.  Instead be sure to use the Location directive. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#mod_dav_svn-fsmap

Comment: If you use apache 2.4 use require all granted instead

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had `E175002` because of missing DNS records of Subversion server.

Answer (score 1):

I had 2 issues:

a) The `svn` folder was not readable by apache user

b) Possibly the `Directory` was not setup correctly

In my example, SVN repository is installed under `/home/svn`.

1) `chown apache.svn -R /home/svn`

2) Modify subversion.conf:

```
<VirtualHost svn.xxx.com:443>
    ServerName svn.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /home/svn/

  <Directory "/home/svn/">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options None
    </Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|jsp|html|htm|php?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

alias /svn /home/svn

<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /home/svn
 SVNListParentPath On
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Repositorio Subversion"
 AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/dav_svn.passwd
 Require valid-user
 allow from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the windows password and then I have tried checking out the code and I end up with the above unknown host error.

I have restarted eclipse and restarted virtual machine where my eclipse has been set up.

Now I am able to checkout. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but the cause for the error was, that I am behind a proxy server. I could resolve this issue by configuring SVN to use this proxy server.
Details how to do this can be found in the following discussion:

[How to configure a HTTP proxy for svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491180/how-to-configure-a-http-proxy-for-svn)

Answer (score 0):

in OSX environment, can check ~/.subversion/server
if you are behind proxy, can edit http-proxy-xxxxx attribute

Answer (score 0):

This same problem happened for me and it was possible to finish checking the project out by running the `UPDATE` SVN command on the incomplete checked out folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Code Composer Studio today where only one of the four files I was trying to commit produced the error. Using the command line solved it for me.

More detail:
No commands from the plugin would clear the error, but commit from the command line worked fine. (That likely means either a bug or misconfiguration in the plugin. But as long as the CLI works, I can live with it. The plugin--subclipse--seems to be no longer supported, so I use it when it seems to work, and fall back to the command line when it doesn't. So far, every issue that's appeared in the plugin has not occurred with the command line.)