# SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn/Repository2/!svn/vcc/default' 400 Bad Request

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am newbie in setting up the jenkins for auto check-out and build generation.

I have created the new project in jenkin with Build a free-style software project.
As I want to checkout first from SVN I have selected subversion and enter repository URL and its credentials.

My subversion plugin version is :2.2 and Jenkins 1.559
And now when I try to run this job it gives following exceptions:

```
Checking out https://punedc.dcpune.yash.local/svn/Repository2/WelcomeJava at revision '2014-04-15T10:17:08.288 +0530'
ERROR: Failed to check out "https://punedc.dcpune.yash.local/svn/Repository2/WelcomeJava"
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn/Repository2/!svn/vcc/default': 400 Bad Request 
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:207)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:475)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:838)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:19)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:8)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1029)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1010)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:935)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:870)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1320)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:518)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1700)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn/Repository2/!svn/vcc/default': 400 Bad Request  
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:141)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.createDefaultErrorMessage(HTTPRequest.java:455)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.readError(HTTPRequest.java:290)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:215)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:480)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:324)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:200)
    ... 27 more
```

I googled this exception but still could not identify any solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I am running jenkins as windows services.

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue and solution for it in the below thread.

[SVN Error E175002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509251/svn-error-e175002)

Comment: But I am not able to find the httpd.conf file. I am running jenkins without tomcat.

Comment: Which authentication are you using in Subversion Apache HTTP or svnserver ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with the following stack trace. The problem was that the disk space was not enough in the JENKINS workspace directory.

```
ERROR: Failed to check out https://collaborate.bt.com/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/branches/FF_RelAS_CodeImprovement
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:839)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:19)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:8)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:908)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:889)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:872)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:848)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:786)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1750)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155009: REPORT request failed on '/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default'
svn: E155009: Error processing command 'cp-and-translate' in '/home/fforct01/.jenkins/workspace/FF_Revamp/lib'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:771)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: svn: E155009: REPORT request failed on '/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.wrap(SVNErrorMessage.java:407)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: svn: E155009: Error processing command 'cp-and-translate' in '/home/fforct01/.jenkins/workspace/FF_Revamp/lib'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:141)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNLogRunner.runCommand(SVNLogRunner.java:476)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNLog.run(SVNLog.java:303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.runLogs(SVNAdminArea.java:586)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.runLogs(SVNAdminArea.java:569)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15$SVNDirectoryInfo.runLogs(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:1608)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.closeDir(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCancellableEditor.closeDir(SVNCancellableEditor.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.DAVEditorHandler.endElement(DAVEditorHandler.java:475)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.BasicDAVHandler.endElement(BasicDAVHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:911)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:876)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:480)
    ... 32 more
java.io.IOException: Failed to check out https://collaborate.bt.com/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/branches/FF_RelAS_CodeImprovement
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:110)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:908)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:889)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:872)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:848)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:786)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1750)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:839)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:19)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:8)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:99)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155009: REPORT request failed on '/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default'
svn: E155009: Error processing command 'cp-and-translate' in '/home/fforct01/.jenkins/workspace/FF_Revamp/lib'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:771)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: svn: E155009: REPORT request failed on '/svn/fos-operate-fieldforecast/!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.wrap(SVNErrorMessage.java:407)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: svn: E155009: Error processing command 'cp-and-translate' in '/home/fforct01/.jenkins/workspace/FF_Revamp/lib'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:141)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNLogRunner.runCommand(SVNLogRunner.java:476)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNLog.run(SVNLog.java:303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.runLogs(SVNAdminArea.java:586)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.runLogs(SVNAdminArea.java:569)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15$SVNDirectoryInfo.runLogs(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:1608)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.closeDir(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCancellableEditor.closeDir(SVNCancellableEditor.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.DAVEditorHandler.endElement(DAVEditorHandler.java:475)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.BasicDAVHandler.endElement(BasicDAVHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:911)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:876)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:480)
    ... 32 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click the project the Subversion>Working Copy>Cleanup. It work on mine, if ur using netbeans. gl