# SVNRDUMP via PROXY

Tags: svn, proxy

Can we take dump of a repository using svnrdump where the server connects to the internet via a proxy?
I tried as below--

```
ab001234:/home/jboss/temp $ svnrdump dump http://example.com/svn/repo1 > full.dmp
svnrdump: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http:/example.com/svn/repo1'
svnrdump: E670002: Name or service not known
ab001234:/home/jboss/temp $ svnrdump dump http://example.com/svn/repo1 --username myname --password mypassword > full.dmp
svnrdump: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://example.com/svn/repo1'
svnrdump: E670002: Name or service not known
ab001234:/home/jboss/temp $
```

Comment: By "the server", do you mean to say that the computer you're running `svnrdump` on uses the proxy? Have you configured SVN for the proxy like in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491180/how-to-configure-a-http-proxy-for-svn)?

Comment: Yes, the server is in corporate intranet and to access internet, it uses proxy without user authentication. We have configured the specific URL http://example.com in the proxy itself so as to allow this traffic to outside world. Yes, I also tried by configuring the proxy settings at the admin console of collabnet edge but still the svnrdump doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got it working.
Added the proxy details in the servers file in the users home directory under `.subversion` folder (`ab001234:/home/myprofile/.subversion`).
Wonder why it didn't work when I added it in the proxy settings of the Collabnet Edge console portal.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy settings in SVN Edge have nothing to do with `svnrdump` as far as I can guess.

On the computer where you launch `svnrdump` configure `http-proxy-host` & `http-proxy-port` options. Read [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea) for the instructions.

Comment: Nope. Tried that already. These are meant for SVN client access. But I need to make it work for `svnrdump`. The entries that we provide in edge ends up in the servers file under svn_client_config as `http-proxy-host` and `http-proxy-port`.

Comment: I even tried to configure the proxy in `csvn.conf` file too-- 
`HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234`

Comment: @BIJUNATOR `svnrdump` technically is a Subversion client. BTW, `Name or service not known` error may indicate a problem with the values you enter in the options. You don't need to enter protocol in the `http-proxy-host`. Enter just `example.com` without `http://`.

Comment: I haven't. It automatically creates the entry in the servers file under svn_client_config when I save the proxy details via edge.
`ab001234:.../csvn/data/svn_client_config $ cat servers`
`[global]`
`http-proxy-host = example.com`
`http-proxy-port = 1234`
`ab001234:.../csvn/data/svn_client_config $`

Comment: The protocol was given in fact in the file csvn.conf files since it explicitly say so--
`# If your server needs to use an http proxy for outbound network connections,`
`# provide the url here. For example, if your proxy does not require`
`# authentication, the property will look like:`
`# HTTP_PROXY=protocol://hostname:port`
`# To set up with authentication, the property should look like this:`
`# HTTP_PROXY=protocol://username:password@hostname:port`
`#HTTP_PROXY=`