# How do I configure the SVN HTTP proxy from the command line?

Tags: svn, build, dependency-management, build-script, build-system

I script the set up of my build environment. (So the build process can bootstrap itself if it finds itself running on a clean image).

As part of this process, certain dependencies are retrieved from public SVN repositories.

The build machines sit behind a proxy, so I need to configure SVN to use the proxy.

Several of the options that come immediately to mind are unpalatable for various reasons:

- I could edit the ~/.subversion/servers file manually, but I would far rather keep the build process as self-contained and as automated as possible.
- Alternatively, I could "proxy" the various public subversion repositories with an internal "dependencies" repository, but this adds to the number of moving parts that need to be maintained.
- Finally, I could write a script to check the configuration file and modify it (if needed), but this seems like overkill for what should be a trivial part of the build process.

Ideally, I should be able to specify the proxy from the command line, but it is not obvious that this is possible. What is the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: OK, so it looks like I can use the following commands to set the proxy (Which I still have to test):  svn propset --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<PROXY>; svn propset --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=<PORT> (However: the proxy for our browsers is set automatically, so I am still working out if I need to download and parse the proxy configuration script).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[SVNBook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/) to the rescue!

1. As you've already mentioned, you can add SVN configuration options to `svn` command-line client.

   See [SVNBook | `--config-option` command-line reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.config_option).

   > Sets, for the duration of the command, the value of a runtime
   >   configuration option. CONFSPEC is a string which specifies the
   >   configuration option namespace, name and value that you'd like to
   >   assign, formatted as **FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]**. In this syntax, FILE
   >   and SECTION are the runtime configuration file (either config or
   >   servers) and the section thereof, respectively, which contain the
   >   option whose value you wish to change. OPTION is, of course, the
   >   option itself, and VALUE the value (if any) you wish to assign to the
   >   option. For example, to temporarily disable the use of the automatic
   >   property setting feature, use
   >   --config-option=config:miscellany:enable-auto-props=no. **You can use this option multiple times to change multiple option values
   >   simultaneously.**

   Here is the sample command-line:

   `svn checkout ^`
     `--config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<PROXY-HOST> ^`
     `--config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=<PORT> <REPO-URL> <LWC-DIR>`
2. Or use `--config-dir` to point `svn` command-line client to customized configuration file.

   `--config-dir DIR`

   > Instructs Subversion to read configuration information from the
   >   specified directory instead of the default location (.subversion in
   >   the user's home directory).

Comment: Well, the config-option does not seem to work too well, as I get the following two errors:   svn: invalid option --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=<PORT>   svn: invalid option --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<HOST> .... I am now trying the --config-dir option instead.

Comment: It took me a little while to figure out, but the full command to use is: svn checkout --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<PROXY-HOST> --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=<PORT>                    <REPO-URL> <LWC-DIR>