# Is there a way to access Subversion's proxy settings programmatically or from command-line?

Tags: svn

Subversion keeps its proxy configuration in the `~/.subversion/servers` file (https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers).

Is there a way to access this information through the Subversion command line client, similar to something like `git config --global --list`?

I'm looking for a way to access this information for both read and write access, and I would like to avoid parsing the file.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't check this via svn.exe. You should check the file itself. BTW, possible duplicate of [How do I configure the SVN HTTP proxy from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649199/how-do-i-configure-the-svn-http-proxy-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks, yes, that looks pretty similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't seem to be possible to get the proxy configuration through the svn executable, I resorted to using an embedded Python script. Why Python? Since it has the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module, which allows to read/write INI-style files:

```
    if $(command -v svn &> /dev/null) && $(command -v python &> /dev/null) ; then
        python - <<END
import ConfigParser, os
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.expanduser('~/.subversion/servers'))
if (config.has_section('global')):
    proxy_host = ''
    proxy_port = ''
    proxy_exceptions = ''
    if (config.has_option('global', 'http-proxy-host')):
        proxy_host = config.get('global', 'http-proxy-host')
    if (config.has_option('global', 'http-proxy-port')):
        proxy_port = config.get('global', 'http-proxy-port')
    if (config.has_option('global', 'http-proxy-exceptions')):
        proxy_exceptions = config.get('global', 'http-proxy-exceptions')
    print 'http-proxy-host      : ' + proxy_host
    print 'http-proxy-port      : ' + proxy_port
    print 'http-proxy-exceptions: ' + proxy_exceptions
END
    fi
```

This code reads the `~/.subversion/servers` file and prints the values. Similar code can be used to change the proxy values.