# SVN unable to connect to host after proxy setup

Tags: svn, proxy

I am trying to checkout a svn repo on a VM (which I am SSHed into). All ports to the external net are blocked by a firewall, so all HTTP traffic should be routed through this proxy: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128. I SVN to use this proxy by adding the following lines to: /etc/subversion/servers

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
http-proxy-port = 3128
```

I am still unable to checkout SVN repos. For example, when I try to checkout the freeBSD repo using the following command:

```
svn co svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/sbin/routed
```

I get the following error:

```
svn: E000101: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/svin/routedsvn'
svn: E000101: Can't connect to host 'svn.freebsd.org': Network is unreachable
```

I even tried:

```
svn co http://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/sbin/routed
```

Can anyone point me towards what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy has to be set to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` without specifying any protocol. Remove `http://` from the proxy address.

However, `http-proxy-host` has nothing to do with access via `svn://` access scheme. `svn://` (svnserve) is a protocol specific to Subversion. `http-proxy-host` works for HTTP(S) connections only.

So you have two options:

- Use HTTP(S) URL to the repository. E.g. like this `http://svn.freebsd.org/base/`.
- Configure a tunnel as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82530/761095) and in related threads.

Comment: I tried that. I still get the same error mentioned above.

Comment: @SivaDotRender then contact admin of the proxy server for assistance.

Comment: the proxy seems to be working fine. I use it for other utilities like `apt-get`. Just wondering is there is anything else I'm overlooking here